# Outlook Record Detail layout page not found

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

Im trying to create a lightning component for Outlook Inbox that will display all the records from my custom object.
My problem right now is that when I click on the object's name it will re-direct me to the desktop record layout instead of Inbox record layout.
Can anyone help me with this??? 
Thank you,

href code:

```
<a href="{! '/' + r.Id}" target="_blank">{!r.Name}</a>
```

Picture of my component:

[image]

Comment: have you tried using record inside modal popup on click?

Comment: Can you please explain it further, i never heard of that before